# Get reference to variable inside anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

Say I'm writing a greasemonkey/chrome extension script that needs access to a variable that's inside of a closured anonymous method, like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var goldenTreasure = "Tasty Loins";
}
```

is there **any**way I can get to that goldenTreasure and have me some tasty loins?

### note: I can't edit the above method, it's on a site, and my extension needs access to the treasure inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to access a `var` that's inside a closure as it is a `private variable` that is technically hidden inside the containing closure. Only functions inside that closure may have access to it.

Comment: thank's for your help, check the clarification in my question now. the code is pre-existing on a site, and I'm just trying to get to the treasure inside with my injected script

Comment: @vvMINOvv There is no way to access those loins for you unfortunately :P

Answer (score 0):

Define the variable outside, then assign value inside.

```
var goldenTreasure;

$(document).ready(function() {
    goldenTreasure = "Tasty Loins";
}
```

Or another way of doing it is to assign it as a property of the window object

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.goldenTreasure = "Tasty Loins";
}
```

Comment: thank's for your help, check the clarification in my question now. the code is pre-existing on a site, and I'm just trying to get to the treasure inside with my injected script

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a variable outside of the anonymous function and just assign the one inside as its value. (do it this way if you plan to reuse `goldenTreasure` for another purpose inside the anonymous function.

```
var some;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var goldenTreasure = "Tasty Loins";
    some = goldenTreasure;
}
```

Comment: thank's for your help, check the clarification in my question now. the code is pre-existing on a site, and I'm just trying to get to the treasure inside with my injected script